# How should structured data look for WordPress categories and tags?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, blog, tags, categories

Working on rebuilding a WordPress blog with structured data I researched the site and ran across "[Using Schema.org for blogging: Article VS BlogPosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/using-schema-org-for-blogging-article-vs-blogposting)" and decided to use the `Article` schema.

Planning the site accordingly, wireframing, and structuring the code I found the usage of breadcrumbs and read:

- [Breadcrumb using Schema.org rich snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32871/breadcrumb-using-schema-org-rich-snippets)
- [Should the first breadcrumb not be the home page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95231/should-the-first-breadcrumb-not-be-the-home-page)

but when it comes to categories and tags in WordPress which should you use with breadcrumbs or would both be identified as breadcrumbs?  How would the data look for a tag list like:

```
foo,
bar,
doo,
don,
```

with a category of:

```
monday
wednesday
```

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly you ask. The breadcrumbs show the parent pages of the current page (which could include categories and/or tags, depending on your information architecture). But why do you ask about structured data / Schema.org? You can mark up the breadcrumbs with it, sure, but isn’t your question more about what the breadcrumbs should contain, not how to mark them up?

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding then please correct me but my end goal is to increase my seo and better take advantage of structured data.  If categories or tags shouldn't be structured then let me know.

Comment: Using structured data for categories/tags is fine. Using structured data for breadcrumbs is fine, too. But what I don’t understand is why you make a connection between these two. What is their relationship? These are typically two separate things, e.g., you could have the breadcrumbs at the top of the page and the categories/tags at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Structured data doesn't help rankings. At best it can get Google to enhance the display of your site in the search results. [Google maintains a gallery of all they ways they use schema.org markup in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery).

Google does allow you to mark up the breadcrumbs of a page for display instead of the URL in the results. You could choose either categories or tags for that.  Categories would usually make the most sense because they have a hierarchy that would fit well into breadcrumbs. There is no benefit to marking up both categories and tags.  I wasn't able to find data on how much breadcrumb markup might change the click through rate (CTR) from the search results.   It certainly should have some effect, but I would expect it to be modest since most users click on the big blue titles and not on the green URLs or breadcrumbs.

Google says that they have an article carousel, but I've never seen that in my search results, so I doubt that your `Article` markup will have much effect.  It would probably be most effective for newsy articles for which Google had determined that the queries deserve freshness (QDF).  I think Google is most likely to show the article carousel for news related searches.